# JSX element 'h1' has no corresponding closing tag

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code to learn ReactJs, but I don't know why for HTML code I am getting "JSX element has no corresponding closing tag" error. Please see the picture.

[image]

Code Before I save the file in Visual Studio Code IDE

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return ( 
            <h1>Hello React</h1>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render( < HelloWorld / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Code after I save the file in Visual Studio Code IDE

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return ( <
            h1 > Hello React < /h1>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render( < HelloWorld / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Change `< ...     h1>` to `<h1>` and `< ...     /h1>` to `</h1>`.

Comment: Thank you! James for reply. I did that but on save command it again changed  <h1> to <... h1>

Comment: I have noticed that this is VSC formatter issue and I have set it to false on save, but don't know what will be the right solution for this. How to format it correctly on save?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weird formatting when saving react project file in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72150461/weird-formatting-when-saving-react-project-file-in-vscode)

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue.  Each time I saved my code was reformatted resulting in a similar the error to that posed in the question.  I resolved it by selectively disabling code formatting extensions I'd installed in VS Code.  I found disabling the "Beautify" extension (by HookyQR) resolved the problem.

Note:I found you can disable an extension for either all VS Code instances or just a Workspace, allowing you keep it active on a Workspace by Workspace basis.

Comment: seems like the solution disabling "Beautify" works! but still have the same warning there.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I change the file extension for js to ts and change it back to js and that fix the issue.
I think vs code is confused between typeScript and JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is related to Visual Studio Code's Language Mode. To solve it, change the Language Mode from "JavaScript" to "JavaScrip React" or just "react" (any of the two works). You can change Language Mode at the bottom toolbar of VSC (see the picture below).

Click on it, search for JavaScript React, and select it. Like this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Comment: I think this is the best one

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to install Prettier as the last extension.

If you already have Prettier installed:

- Uninstall Prettier
- Restart VS Code
- Install Prettier
- Restart VS Code

This solved the problem for me and now Format on Save works!

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me. Disabled a lot of themes and other add-ons (many). No use. Re-installed Prettier: worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.When i save the file it was reformatted with the formatter that i used (prettier). I uninstalled it and re-open the visual studio code.It worked for me!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
Please note that you do not add much to [myra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56889184/2359227). If you don't have what to add, please consider removing this post.

Answer (score 0):

if there are any typescript extensions installed, remove them.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1.Press Ctrl + shift + P to open search fields in VS Code.

2.Type settings.json. Don't press enter until the next step.

3.Select `Open Workspace Settings(JSON). This should open the workspace settings file in json format. It maybe empty for you.

4.Now paste this json inside the file.

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "*.js": "javascriptreact"
    }
}
```

5.save file