# JSX element 'h1' has no corresponding closing tag.ts(17008)

Tags: reactjs, frontend, babeljs, jsx, mern

Whenever I Save the index.js in react.js@17.0.1 version file in vscode, code is reformatted in ugly way and shows the error as in this picture:

[image: picture]

I have tried all the possible solutions available on Google, but no results.

From uninstalling and reinstalling vscode to prettier uninstall, restart vscode, install again and restart vscode again, create-react-app again and again and all that. How can I get on the right track?

Comment: @Rahul Jindal please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47161385/jsx-element-h1-has-no-corresponding-closing-tag

Comment: index.js? I think it should be index.jsx.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSX element 'h1' has no corresponding closing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47161385/jsx-element-h1-has-no-corresponding-closing-tag)

Comment: @AjeetShah I did create-react-app reacttutorial and just made environment for me.Even tried with .jsx but didn't work. I have downloaded all the recommended extensions form Reactjs or JSX , but no result.  I have tried everything available on stackoverflow regarding this. But none of them works, that's why i post this question. I know it's already there. I hope I get solution of this as soon as possible, I wanna learn react and I am just obsessed with this error. Tried googling , stackoverflow , Youtube. It's been 15 hrs I'm struggling with this

Comment: @RahulJindal So, this issue is there only when you use VSCode, and you are able to, say, use a notepad to save and run the React project successfully, right?

Comment: If the problem is only with VSCode, you can try reinstalling it or try a different code editor like Atom or Sublime.

Answer (score 1):

- The reason for it is using a formatting extension.

Steps to solve the issue

1. Disable the formatting extension.
2. Remove the extra spaces from the code.
3. Save it

That should solve the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Rename your file extension from `.js` file to `.jsx`

At the bottom of the screen, you'll see the language mode (currently set to Javascript).

-> Click on 'Set Language Mode'

-> Then set your Language Mode to 'JavaScript React'

Answer (score 1):

Changing the file from index.js to index.jsx and re-writing the  tags as well as the "hello world" worked for me.

Then, I changed back the index.jsx to index.js and the error didn't come up again.. Not sure why...

Answer (score 1):

On Visual Studio Code look for a wheel icon , that lies under the account icon [ which is like a human figure ] and is on lower left side in my case.
If you hover over the wheel => *Manage* label appears.
Click on the wheel and a menu pops ups where you'll see *Extensions* . Click on Extensions . Now look for JS-CSS-HTML-formatter among your extensions . Right next to *JS-CSS-HTML-formatter* you'll see again the wheel icon ; click it and choose from the pop up menu Disable or Uninstall

For further documentation ,consult :
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to rename your file from "`.js`" to "`.jsx`"

Then, you can try this syntax :

```
const element = <h1>this is something written in js</h1>;

ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

=> JSX tags (`<Component />`) are not standard javascript and have no special meaning if you put them inside a `.js` file

=> if you want to create element in a `.js` file, take a look to https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement or  https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html

Answer (score 0):

To use `HTML` syntax you need to specify `.jsx` or `.tsx` file extension.

If you wish to make React elements without JSX syntax use `createElement(...)`

> **Creating React Elements**
>
> We recommend using JSX to describe what your UI should look like. Each JSX element is just syntactic sugar for calling React.createElement(). You will not typically invoke the following methods directly if you are using JSX.
>
> - `createElement()`
> - `createFactory()`

source: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is because of your vscode's formatter extension .be sure to format your code with js code formatter.

Answer (score 0):

it's so simple, go to this website : https://www.convertsimple.com/convert-html-to-jsx/ and paste html code and it will be converted to jsx

it worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).