# VS code editor automatically gives a space between the characters of fragments and react native components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, frontend, expo

[image]

I am creating a sign in page in react native. The issue is, when I start typing the component name and fragments the code editor automatically gives a space between the characters.

Also, this is the error message I am getting in my code editor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weird formatting when saving react project file in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72150461/weird-formatting-when-saving-react-project-file-in-vscode)

Answer (score 0):

[make sure did you change the language in bottom of your vscode (in My case I choose Python.) you have to choose javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px4X6.png)

Comment: derive the image is better